# adding options to IKSaveOptions?

Tags: objective-c, imagekit, iksaveoptions

I have an ImageKit program that needs to be able to save images, so I'm using the IKSaveOptions accessory view, to allow the user to choose a file type, etc.

However, I want to remove some of the options, and add a checkbox to the panel for TIFFs. Alternatively, I want to add a type of file. However I can't figure out how to do this. I assume I'm going to have to subclass off of IKSaveOptions and over-ride something,  but I can't find any sample code or documentation that tells me how to do this.

ETA: In particular, I need to be able to allow the user to distinguish between multi-page tiff, and a bunch of single-page tiffs with a page-number appended.

ETA: So, SO is telling me "I have only a few hours before the bounty expires so I should choose an answer" But ... there are no answers! (You'd think that SO would be smart enough to see that, but oh well B-)

Comment: For the record: I hate it when I do a google search, and the only possible useful hit is a link to the question that I JUST ASKED AT SO... D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

IKSaveOptions is inherited from NSObject. Real accessory view is built internally and is not accessible with public API:

```
@interface IKSaveOptions : NSObject
{
@private
    void *  _privateData;
    id      _saveOptionsView;
}
```

So your best bet is to build your own save dialog accessory view with blackjack and hookers. You can start with NSView custom view in interface builder. Then it is simply:

```
NSSavePanel *saveDialog = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[saveDialog setAccessoryView:mySaveAccessoryView];
```

Answer (score 0):

VB is right, but you can get the accessory view from the NSSavePanel after it has been set by the IKSaveOptions object.